# Generating keywords from the article

Tags: keyword, tagging

How can we generate important keywords for any random article ?Does there exist any existing algorithm or tool to get the important keywords from the given text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux you can just use grep command to get the lines which has important keywords.

Eg: $ cat file_name.txt |grep key_word

The above command will display only the lines which has the specified key_word.

Please specify more details, like what type of file(eg:txt or doc files etc) More information about which programming language and Operating system you use to get a proper answer

Comment: let us assume java is used and i have a text file containing the article.By only having the text I need to figure out which tags can be given to this article just from the content and heading of the article.